# cl_http_utility not normalizing my url. Why?

Tags: url, unicode, abap

Via an enterpreise service consumer I connect to a webservice, which returns me some data, and also url's.

However, I tried all methods of the mentioned class above and NO METHOD seems to convert the unicode-characters inside my url into the proper readable characters.... ( in this case '=' and ';' ) ...

The only method, which runs properly is "is_valid_url", which returns false, when I pass url's like this:

```
http://not_publish-workflow-dev.hq.not_publish.com/lc/content/forms/af/not_publish/request-datson-internal/v01/request-datson-internal.html?taskId\u003d105862\u0026wcmmode\u003ddisabled
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4):

It seems that this format is for json values. Usually `=` and `&` don't need to be written with the `\u` prefix. To decode all `\u` characters, you may use this code:

```
DATA(json_value) = `http://not_publish-workflow-dev.hq.not_publish.com/lc`
                && `/content/forms/af/not_publish/request-datson-internal/v01`
                && `/request-datson-internal.html?taskId\u003d105862\u0026wcmmode\u003ddisabled`.

FIND ALL OCCURRENCES OF REGEX '\\u....' IN json_value RESULTS DATA(matches).
SORT matches BY offset DESCENDING.
LOOP AT matches ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<match>).
  DATA hex2 TYPE x LENGTH 2.
  hex2 = to_upper( substring( val = json_value+<match>-offset(<match>-length) off = 2 ) ).
  DATA(uchar) = cl_abap_conv_in_ce=>uccp( hex2 ).
  REPLACE SECTION OFFSET <match>-offset LENGTH <match>-length OF json_value WITH uchar.
ENDLOOP.

ASSERT json_value = `http://not_publish-workflow-dev.hq.not_publish.com/lc`
                && `/content/forms/af/not_publish/request-datson-internal/v01`
                && `/request-datson-internal.html?taskId=105862&wcmmode=disabled`.
```

Comment: Hi. Look, this cannot be the reason. I know, that I can substitute this by myself, I simply wonder, why this does not work by sap standard ....

Comment: It's specific to JSON, not to HTTP, hence it's not done in this CL_HTTP_UTILITY. But it's not clear in your question where you exactly get this URL.

Comment: This formatting is specific to json? I really doubt it, but I will ask the developer. I get a lot of data from a java webservice, appearently consuming adobe workflow Services

Comment: In HTTP, characters are escaped using % (`%3D` for `=`, `%26` for `&`)

Answer (score 0):

I hate to answer my own questions, but anyway, I found an own solution, via manually replacing those unicodes. It is similar to Sandra's idea, but able to convert ANY unicode.

I share it here, just in case, any person might also need it.

```
  DATA: lt_res_tab TYPE  match_result_tab.
  DATA(valid_url) = url.

  FIND ALL OCCURRENCES OF REGEX '\\u.{4}' IN valid_url RESULTS lt_res_tab.

  WHILE lines( lt_res_tab )  > 0.

    DATA(match) = substring( val = valid_url off = lt_res_tab[ 1 ]-offset len = lt_res_tab[ 1 ]-length ).
    DATA(hex_unicode) = to_upper( match+2 ).
    DATA(char) = cl_abap_conv_in_ce=>uccp( uccp = hex_unicode ).

    valid_url = replace( val = valid_url off = lt_res_tab[ 1 ]-offset len = lt_res_tab[ 1 ]-length with = char ).

    FIND ALL OCCURRENCES OF REGEX '\\u.{4}' IN valid_url RESULTS lt_res_tab.

  ENDWHILE.


  WRITE / url.
  WRITE / valid_url.
```

Comment: It's almost the same algorithm, what is different with my proposal ? (mine also converts ANY Unicode character).

Comment: Okay, initial json_value changed as per your advice. Looks better now.

Comment: No need for that, I like Your answers and I respect You generally. Keep on, till next tjme. BTW, i have a question in here regarding a dynamic selscreen 1000. Maybe, you can help, too. By the way does section keep track of changes to the initial string and offsets?

Comment: from my opinion, you should at least upvote sandras response or use it as an answer. keep the spirit alive here...